# How to install cmake on Windows 64 bit

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, cmake

The download page for cmake only shows a 32 bit installer for windows. Any idea how to install it on 64 windows systems.

Comment: You can use the 32 bit version of CMake to build (setup) 64 bit applications - there is no reason to have a 64 bit CMake version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is really no reason for a 64bit native CMake.  CMake is only building the *configuration*, so you can use it to build configurations for 64bit software, even with the 32bit version.

That being said, if you truly want a 64bit native version, you could always download the source and compile it.  There is no 64bit installer, however.

Answer (score 11):

The 32 bit version works perfectly even on 64 bit Windows. I've used it, and it works.

EDIT: It looks like CMake is now available in both 32-bit and 64-bit flavors. Just go to their website and you can get the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 2):

A 64-bit Windows installer is now available from the download page: https://cmake.org/download