# What do I need to compile a Stata plugin for PostgreSQL on Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, stata

I am an avid user of PostgreSQL and I would like to encourage others to use it. Many people in my (academic) circles use Stata and I have managed to compile *on Mac OS X* a plugin that allows Stata to access PostgreSQL directly; this gets rave reviews from those who have tried it (though I think there's room for improvement). However, many of my Stata-using colleagues run Windows and it would be great if this plug-in could be made to work for them too.

Below are the steps I used to compile the plug-in on OS X (the plug-in comes from a site at Oxford); I copied these steps from my blog [here](https://iangow.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/pulling-data-into-stata-from-postgresql-in-mac-os-x/).

My question is: How would these instructions need to be modified to work on Windows? (I don't have access to Windows, so if you could confirm that you can modify this to work for you, that would be great.)

Note that I have PostgreSQL installed from MacPorts and I also have `wget` (`sudo port install wget`).

### 1. Get file from Stata and Oxford site

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://code.ceu.ox.ac.uk/stata/pgload-0.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf pgload-0.1.tar.gz
mkdir ~/Downloads/stata
cd ~/Downloads/stata/
wget http://www.stata.com/plugins/stplugin.c
wget http://www.stata.com/plugins/stplugin.h
```

### 2. Edit Makefile

```
vim ~/Downloads/pgload-0.1/Makefile
```

The last step opens up the Makefile. I make changes to five lines (the last two will differ if you installed PostgreSQL 9.3 from somewhere other than MacPorts).

```
PLUGIN_SYS=APPLEMAC
INSTALL_LOCATION=~/Library/Application\ Support/Stata/ado/personal
STATAPLUG_INC=~/Downloads/stata
PQ_INC=/opt/local/include/postgresql93
PG_SERVER_INC=/opt/local/include/postgresql93/server
```

I then save and exit. Then

### 3. Compile and install

```
cd ~/Downloads/pgload-0.1
make
sudo make install
```

### 4. Add loadsql.ado file

The `loadsql.ado` file is placed in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Stata/ado/personal` and contains the following:

```
program define loadsql
*! Load the output of an SQL file into Stata, version 1.4 (iandgow@gmail.com)
version 13.1
syntax using/, CONN(string)

#delimit;
tempname sqlfile exec line;

file open `sqlfile' using `"`using'"', read text;
file read `sqlfile' `line';

while r(eof)==0 {;
    local `exec' `"``exec'' ``line'' 
     "';
    file read `sqlfile' `line';
};

file close `sqlfile';

* display "`conn'";

pgload "`conn'" "``exec''", clear;
* pgload "``dsn''" "SELECT permno, date, abs(prc) AS prc FROM crsp.dsf LIMIT 10", clear;

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of work, I was successfully able to build and run pgload. There were some errors along the way, which I have struck through below. After testing the plugin however, I would suggest just using ODBC as it is easier to set up and a tiny bit faster.

I'm running Windows 7 x64, postgres 9.3 64-bit, stata-SE 11.2 64-bit

set up Visual Studio (VS Express 2015 for Desktop) for PGSQL extension (Followed http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/)

add include directory for stata files

added libpq.lib to linked libraries

changed "char tmpsql_buf[tmpsql_buf_len + 1];" to "char tmpsql_buf[1024 + 1];" because of an error with needing constant values here.

<del>changed strncpy to strncpy_s (e.g. `strncpy_s(svalue, 244, valuetmp, 244);`      probably not needed but had warnings about security here)</del>

<del>changed strcat to strcat_s (e.g. `strcat_s(stata_mac_vars, sizeof stata_mac_vars, fname);` probably not needed but had warnings about security here)</del>

changed bzero to memset (e.g. `memset(tmpsql_buf,'\0', tmpsql_buf_len + 1);`)

aliased _strnicmp to strncasecmp (`#define strncasecmp _strnicmp`
)

got strptime.c and strptime.h from somewhere on the internet and put these with the stata files; added an include in pg.c `#include <strptime.h>` after the include for time.h.

got libintl.h and added it to the PostgreSQL include directory (from here: https://gist.github.com/ringerc/d57978ca0d3a3a13b5d7). For some reason these were not in the postgresql 9.3 x64 server includes.

added path to postgres.exe to the windows PATH environment variable

made sure architectures match x64 (64bit) for STATA, PGSQL, and Target machine (etc.)

Build the project -- **Compiles DLL OK with no warnings**

Copy the pg.dll, pglaod.ado, and pgload.hlp to the ado directory

rename pg.dll to pg.plugin

test the plugin with `program pg,plugin` -- **Loads OK with no warnings**

tried to run `pgload "dbname=research host=localhost user=XXX password=XXXX" "SELECT permno, date, abs(prc) AS prc FROM crsp.dsf LIMIT 10",clear`, which should look familiar.
<del>-- **Stata hard crashes with no error message when tried to execute this** (but no worries; Windows is checking for a solution :P )</del> loads as expected

-Joe

P.S. Thanks for your blog/github; I've shamelessly stolen bits from both of them.

Comment: I wonder if those changes are causing problems. I made a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/iangow/pgstata) that might facilitate making tweaks to isolate the problem. I put the OS X-specific edits on a separate branch and I guess the same could be done for Windows.

Comment: You say: "got libintl.h and added it to the PostgreSQL include directory (from here: https://gist.github.com/ringerc/d57978ca0d3a3a13b5d7). For some reason these were not in the postgresql 9.4 server includes." These aren't in my PostgreSQL include directories either.

Comment: Also, are you not using the `makefile`? Do you think it would make a difference if you did? Or are you closely replicating what it's doing anyway? You could use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/download/) (also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964477/how-to-install-cmake-on-windows-64-bit)).

Comment: Perhaps ignore that last comment. You might want to try [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) as discussed on the [Stata page](http://www.stata.com/plugins/#sect5a) to compile in a way that is more consistent with what I did. Also see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/405158/how-to-install-gnu-make-in-windows-7).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @Ian. The changes I made were to get the thing to compile in the first place. With respect to `libintl.h`, it is only needed for WIN32 with NLS enabled, but for some reason is not included in the postgres distribution. I'm not sure how exactly to translate the makefile to a windows specification as visual studios does not use the gcc compiler. I tried Cygwin and mingw (both the one that comes with Cygwin and one that I installed on my Linux box) with no luck. I couldn't even get these to compile.

Comment: I should add that I tried ODBC on both my Macbook and my Linux Box. For Linux, the plugin ran notably faster (x1.5). For my Macbook **ODBC ran slightly faster**. My server is on my Linux box and I connect to this from my mac wirelessly through my local network, which may result in some latency problems. Since ODBC is native to windows, I think it is unlikely that you will see a significant gain in performance from the plugin. Plus, ODBC is super easy to set up on windows.

Comment: @IanGow, you were that some of my changes caused the error. Specifically, the changes to `strncpy` and `str_cat`. I messed up the memory allocation part. I just changed them back to their originals and it seems to work fine now. I'm going to edit the answer to note this. I'm now running some tests to see how the performance compares to ODBC. I just did a quick loop of 10 pulls of 10,000 rows. The plugin did this in 13.30 seconds while ODBC did it in 13.13 seconds. This is similar to what I was getting on my Macbook.

Comment: For 100 repetitions of 100,00 rows, the plugin took 308.74 seconds whereas ODBC took 284.83 seconds.

Comment: The performance differences you show seem pretty trivial and I guess are driven by differences in how the data get shipped back and forth.

I'm not really a Stata user. But I like the idea of the same code working for multiple people who might have different set-ups. I think either ODBC (which I just got working on OS X, though I never really did on Linux when I used it) or `pgload` could support this if users were set-up consistently (e.g., used the same DSN for a given datasource in ODBC).

Comment: One use case I often have is developing a query using pgAdmin3 or something similar and then reading the query and executing from R or Python. Does the ODBC interface in Stata facilitate something like the `loadsql` functionality?

Comment: I agree that the performance difference is very small. The `odbc load` function should work similar to `pgload` with minor changes in the connection string. So in theory, your `loadsql` should work OK either way. You could probably modify this to check for an error loading the plugin and use the plugin if available and odbc otherwise, though I'm not sure it's worth the work. Also note that ODBC allows you also to write to the database, among other things, in addition to reading from it. See `help odbc` in stata for more information.

Comment: Actually pulling a 1,000,000 records over the internet, I saw a pretty significant performance advantage for ODBC. I think this was due to it mapping to less memory-demanding data types (the same query created a 250MB dataset in Stata with ODBC, but 370MB with pgload).

Comment: And I think I will just make an alternative loadsql that uses ODBC (something like this really should be part of the core ODBC functionality in Stata).

Comment: I simply made a new program and it seems to work well. See [here](https://iangow.wordpress.com/2015/08/24/executing-sql-in-a-file-against-an-odbc-source-from-stata/) for details.